# How to create perfect geometric triangle seamless pattern

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, patterns

I'm trying to create a seamless triangle repeat pattern like this:

http://www.redbubble.com/people/bakmannart/works/15661602-my-first-exploring

(sorry, I can't seem to get the image to actually be in this page as it's from RedBubble). However, without these colours necessarily, just the seamless, accurate, geometric pattern; using what is known as the 'triforce' from Legend of Zelda (3 triangles - or 4, depending how you consider it - form together to make one larger triangle). I'm fairly new to Illustrator, however I've tried a few things:

1. **creating a perfect triangle using polygon tool.** rotate/copying the
   triangle into a 'triforce' shape. There is always a few points
   difference though, likely because i'm terrible at maths
2. **trying [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jh-ByTMKPJA)** however, I often get stuck with the line/stroke where the paths of the grid intersect to from triangles. unlike the video's at 3:05 mins, the lines on my work are thicker in some places and basically vary in length.considering i'm using the shape builder tool( as the tutorial denotes to do )it might create some sever inaccuracy in terms of shapes later on. (sorry I can't provide a picture, not enough reputation!)
3. **I've tried just using the move tool and smart guides/locking or whatever it is to accurately
   position triangles together.** I don't know how reliable this is,
   though - and then I have to work out what shape to create (e.g
   hexagon, square) that will repeat well.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing a really simple method. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi Cyrup, Your link died so we can't see the image.

Comment: Do you mean this [Pattern](http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.206320780.5351/ra,unisex_tshirt,x3104,fafafa:ca443f4786,front-c,650,630,900,975-bg,f8f8f8.u1.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Draw hexagon using polygon tool (Shift+drag)

[image]

Draw lines from one point to another as below

[image]

[image]

Select all and Divide with Pathfinder to create individual triangles then ungroup them.

[image]

Fill all triangles with random colors and remove outline, then group them.

[image]

Go to Menu -> Object->Pattern->Make

Select **Tile Type** to **Hex by Column** then done. A pattern is added to the palette.

[image]

Draw desire shape and apply pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The smart guides solution is reliable if you select the print profile when setting up a new document. Then you can position the individual triangles accurately using smart guides.

To build the seamless pattern you can for example construct a [rhomboid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0rF5.jpg) and then use the built-in function to create a pattern. For this group all individual triangles together and then go to `object > pattern > make`.

For another approach I'd recommend [this tutorial](https://creativemarket.com/blog/2015/05/06/learn-the-trick-to-creating-seamless-patterns-in-illustrator).

Comment: Wait so... create a series of random triangles, then group together, then object > pattern > make?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing problems with the stroke size of the grid which is used to make the pattern. If you keep the stoke to be even 1 and the grid points/edges doesn't overlap perfectly over each other, shape builder tool is bound to mess it up.
I'll recommend keeping the stroke to the minimum as possible (if possible keep it 0 but you'll be able to see the grid only when you select it in that case) and then overlap the grid layers perfectly over each other. That will help you in making use of the shape builder tool in a proficient manner.